# Video tag fails in Angular

Tags: html, angular, html5-video, angular7, angular8

I am working on an angular application and I am using video tag in my html. My code is as follows.

```
<div id="display-check-in-open" class="pi-container">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="path to the video" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Video path needs to be given in src. If I give a direct path something like "C:/Users/Videos/video1.mp4" , video is loaded. But I will be getting path dynamically from component in a variable though video name will remain same. In component I have a variable called videoPath and it's value will be something like

```
this.videoPath = C:/Users/Videos/
```

Above path may change dynamically from property file. Now when I am trying to access this videoPath variable in src of video tag, video is not displayed.

I tried as follows:

```
<div id="display-check-in-open" class="pi-container">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src=videoPath + "video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

But above code is not working and also it is showing text in red inside "". i.e video name is shown in red in VS code means above  thing is wrong. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: try `<source src="{{ videoPath + 'video1.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4" />`

Comment: It is able to go video location using this but getting following in console "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME". Any idea how to resolve this

Comment: Becuase that URL is wrong

Comment: video path is right.  I can see video is there

Comment: make sure the URL looks something like this: `"http://localhost:3000/assets/video1.mp4"`
If the `http://` is not there it will not work.  `<source src="{{ 'http://' + 'videoPath + 'video1.mp4' }}" type="video/mp4"`

Comment: mine is a electron angular app and this doesnot have url like http://